# Create multiple dataframes as properties of an instance of a class within if loop

Tags: python, object, dataframe

I have a class, myClass, that I wish to add several dataframes too. At first the class requires a name, and a list of filepaths for an instance to be created:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, name, filepathlist):
        self.name = name
        self.filepathlist = filepathlist
```

The data that is pulled into the instance is not in the desired format. As such I have created a method of the class to format the data and create a property of the class for each file that is read:

```
def formatData(self):

    i = 0
    if i < (len(self.filepathlist) - 1):
        DFRAW = pd.read_csv(self.filepathlist[i], header = 9) #Row 9 is the row that is not blank (all blank auto-skipped)
        DFRAW['DateTime'], DFRAW['dummycol1'] = DFRAW['    ;W;W;W;W'].str.split(';', 1).str
        DFRAW['Col1'], DFRAW['dummycol2'] = DFRAW['dummycol1'].str.split(';', 1).str
        DFRAW['Col2'], DFRAW['dummycol3'] = DFRAW['dummycol2'].str.split(';', 1).str
        DFRAW['Col3'], DFRAW['Col4'] = DFRAW['dummycol3'].str.split(';', 1).str
        DFRAW= DFRAW.drop(['    ;W;W;W;W', 'dummycol1', 'dummycol2', 'dummycol3'], axis = 1)

        #There appears to be an issue with these two lines.
        processedfilename = "MYDFNAME" + str(i)
        self.processedfilename = DFRAW
        i = i + 1
```

I have run the formatting lines of code, those that start with DFRAW, outside of the class and believe these are working correctly.

Somewhere in the script there is an issue with assigning the dataframes as properties of the class; I create a list of filepaths and an instance of the class:

```
filepathlist = [r"file1.csv",r"file2.csv"]
myINST = myClass("MyInstName", filepathlist )
```

Then run the formatting method:

```
myINST.formatData()
```

Now running the following to check that the instance of the class, myINST, has the properties correctly assigned;

```
vars(myINST)
```

But this returns the filepathlist, name and roughly 8000 lines of rows of data from the dataframe. I was expecting the following:

filepathlist, name, MYDFNAME0, MYDFNAME1

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vars` will return all the values of an instance, and since `myClass` have three values: `name`, `filepathlist` and `processedfilename` (which should really be a dataframe), so it will return all.

If you only want the filepathlist, you can access it through `instance_object.field_name`.

`myINST.filepathlist` and this will return `[r"file1.csv",r"file2.csv"]`.

Also, you are probably not doing correct here:

```
processedfilename = "MYDFNAME" + str(i)
self.processedfilename = DFRAW
i = i + 1
```

(1) You are storing dataframe object in a field called  `processedfilename`, which is weird. (2) You are not appending values but rather replacing, thus after the loop, this will only return you the latest data frame in your `filepathlist`.

You should store your dataframe in a better format: list, dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can access your dataframe(s) in `vars()` if you incorporate it into the `__init__` method. Below builds a dictionary of dataframes with keys being original csv file names.

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, name, filepathlist):
        self.name = name
        self.filepathlist = filepathlist
        self.mydataframedict = self.formatData()

    def formatData(self):
        tmp_dict = {}

        for f in self.filepathlist:            
            DFRAW = pd.read_csv(f, header = 9)

            DFRAW['DateTime'], DFRAW['dummycol1'] = DFRAW['    ;W;W;W;W'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW['Col1'], DFRAW['dummycol2'] = DFRAW['dummycol1'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW['Col2'], DFRAW['dummycol3'] = DFRAW['dummycol2'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW['Col3'], DFRAW['Col4'] = DFRAW['dummycol3'].str.split(';', 1).str
            DFRAW = DFRAW.drop(['    ;W;W;W;W', 'dummycol1', 'dummycol2', 'dummycol3'], axis = 1)

            tmp_dict[f] = DFRAW

        return tmp_dict


filepathlist = [r"file1.csv", r"file2.csv"]
myINST = myClass("MyInstName", filepathlist )   

new_dict = myINST.formatData()                # LOCAL VARIABLE (ALSO ACCESSIBLE IN VARS)

print(vars(myINST))

# {'name': 'MyInstName', 'mydataframedict': {'file1.csv': ..., 'file2.csv': ...}, 
# 'filepathlist': ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv']}
```